# Firebase Global Parameter Reporting Quota Just 10 Text Parameters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We've designed every single event parameter on our event logs to monitor on Firebase Analytics Console. But we were shocked when we realized that we had just 10 text parameter quota **per app** :(( It is so sad that Firebase has just too few quotas for Analytics monitoring on console :( What should we do now? Just log those parameters anyway to use with BigQuery one day? :(

Comment: Some even worse news is that Firebase change the number to support as "custom event parameters per project (40 numeric and 10 textual)". Note! it's per project now!
We just failed to add text parameter and confirmed Firebase team that it'd changed. Very bad new policy.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en

Answer (score 6):

I recommend that you link to BigQuery and use the Data Studio [templates](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7200987?hl=en&ref_topic=6386699) to produce reports on your full set of custom event parameters. BigQuery offers free query and storage tiers, so it's a very affordable solution if you reach the limits of parameter reporting in Google Analytics for Firebase.

Comment: But BigQuery is not available on the free tier. Thank you for the response btw!

Comment: Correction, BigQuery does have free query and storage tiers. You can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: But the import from Google Analytics to BigQuery is not free, right? They require you to switch to the Blaze (Pay-as-you-go) price model

Comment: The pay-as-you-go model is a mix of Free and Paid. It's free for products that were already completely free, and free or paid for limited/non-free products as long as you don't exceed the quotas for those services. You'll have to check to see how much it would cost you, in the best case it would still be free.