# Get separately Firebase analytics for level in Unity game

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I managed to set up analytics for my Unity game with Firebase and get data correctly (user gives wrong answer, use help, etc).

My question is how can I get those data separately for each Game instead total for all levels/games?

*For example:*

Level: 1, Game: 3, Wrong answers: 15

Level: 1, Game: 3, Helps used: 5

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, a warning. Read the rules around [event names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/event-names), [parameter names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/parameter-names), and [user property names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/user-property-names). In case you were just wondering why events were't showing up in your dashboard, the space isn't a valid character.

You can use user properties to group all events logged under a user property. There's a really good [iOS specific video](https://youtu.be/DletQHfNGCE), but the content applies to Unity/games with [some api tweaks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/properties).

To filter events based on user properties. So open up your analytics dashboard:

[image: Open analytics dashboard]

And click "Add Filter":

[image: Add filter under dashboard]

You can do this pretty much throughout the Analytics console.

To set a user property, say to indicate that this is game 3, it's a simple:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty("game", 3);
```

Of course, you *may* be logging this as custom parameters on existing events. The data is still there (you can see the custom parameter in an event card), and you can create an audience with this (remember that audiences are accumulative, so users won't leave an audience once they join). The best thing to do is to [export to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765#linking_firebase_analytics_data_to_bigquery) and running custom queries. You can see a video on this [here](https://youtu.be/Ki_F6VCOtXU) as well. You can also generate graphs with [DataStudio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio). This is way more complicated (on the order of it not being reasonable to post examples, sorry for all the links). There's also more in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024270/firebase-analytics-registering-custom-parameters-in-the-console).

I hope that helps!

--Patrick